# round() ignoring zeros in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print some results with 5 numbers after decimal points. I'm using round() function but it doesn't output the last digit if it's a zero. Example:

```
print(str(round(-82.43670009888078, 5)))
print(str(round(49.5211007473081, 5)))
```

Would output:

```
-82.4367
49.5211
```

But I need:

```
-82.43670
49.52110
```

If the last digit isn't 0 it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use .format() to print decimals

```
print ("{:.5f}".format(a))
```

This will print `>>> 49.52110` as desired.

OR

you could simply use

```
format(a, '.5f')
```

Comment: Or using `format(a, '.5f')` directly instead of constructing a format string and calling its `format` method

Comment: Thanks , i will add this to answer